# Coloring div based on condition in laravel blade

Tags: php, css, laravel

I'm trying to use a condition on the value of an array element to set a background color for a div.

The issue is that my syntax is wrong somewhere because the correct color is dumping with the tags around it but it's not actually setting the div to the right color. So it seems the condition is working but my syntax is broken somewhere

```
@foreach($placedList as $placed)
    @if ($placed['AGING'] < 30) 
       $color = "green";
    @elseif ($placed['AGING'] > 30 and $placed['AGING'] < 60) 
       $color = "yellow"
    @else
       $color = "red";
    @endif

    <div class="uk-width-1-10" style="background-color:{{$color}}">{{$placed['AGING']}}</div>

@endforeach
```

What needs to change for this to actually apply?

Comment: You missed `;` after yellow color.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Replace Your code with following

```
@foreach($placedList as $placed)

    @php

    if ($placed['AGING'] < 30) {
       $color = "green";
    }elseif ($placed['AGING'] > 30 and $placed['AGING'] < 60) {
       $color = "yellow";
    }else{
       $color = "red";
    }

    @endphp

    <div class="uk-width-1-10" style="background-color:{{$color}}">{{$placed['AGING']}}</div>

@endforeach
```